# Are there functions that look random but have an easy to calculate integral or sum, preferably closed form?

Tags: probability, functions, random-variables, random-walk

Discrete or continuous.

Would prefer a discrete function f(t) that takes on the values -1, 1 for integer t.

Let's say F(t) is the sum from f(0) to f(t).

Preferably F(t) should look like an example of a random walk. And ideally there is a way to generate a family of functions for f(t), where each F(t) looks like a different sample of a random walk.

And the sum from 0 to t of f, is some easily calculated, or closed form solution, where the time it takes to calculate the sum is less than linear with respect to t.

Comment: You can get something along these lines using Gauss sums (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_sum) although not quite (the upper bound of the sum has to be fixed in advance).